# Connecting Spring Boot to PostgreSQL fails

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to connect Spring Boot back-end to PostgreSQL but get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Der Verbindungsversuch schlug fehl. (->in english: Tried but  
failed to connect.)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:149) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:35) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:47) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
at org.postgresql.jdbc42.AbstractJdbc42Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc42Connection.java:21) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
at org.postgresql.jdbc42.Jdbc42Connection.<init>(Jdbc42Connection.java:28) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:415) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
...
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb 

spring.datasource.username=root 
spring.datasource.password=root   

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>    

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And that's the database springbootdb with the owner root:
[image: my pgAdmin View with the user root as the owner of the database springbootdb]

Why does the connection fail?

Comment: Please delete the duplicate postgresql driver in dependencies, let the version spring give (a 42.x version usually).  Also, there should be a "cause by" exception bellow the one you show

Comment: Oh, sorry, I deleted the duplicate, but that wasn't the problem..
It says something about Spring MVC, but I'm not using MVC?:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]:

Comment: I aslo tried it with 'mariaDB' instead of 'PostgreSQL', but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works.
I first had created another repository, then I wanted to change the way I store my data and created a new entity, service & repository and didn't delete the old one.
There was something wrong with the old one (the entity that was transferred from the service to the repository didn't fit the naming policy anymore, I think? I don't know what it was, but I deleted it to clean up my code and then it worked.